# Zeebus Puzzle #1

Tags: word, rebus

Below is a rebus puzzle for you to solve:

[image: A rebus puzzle]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A 50:50 guess along the same lines:

> Upside down  - as down is written up and there is only one side of the word.

It looks like

> [image]

Comment: Could you explain why there is only one side to the word?

Comment: Ithinkotherwiseitwouldn'tcluesideorifithadbothsidessaysseparatedthenitwouldbepluralsides.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be

> half down, half up (as in the hairstyles)?

New guess

> Picking oneself up when one is down?

Answer (score 4):

Adding to [Tom](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19547/tom)s guess, my guess would be:

> Upside Down & Inside Out.

Because:

> 1.) Upside down: down is written upward. 2.) Inside Out: the "inside" of the word (arbitrarily) is "out" of the picture.

Comment: Nice answer! I like your way of thought. Read my comment above to @PuzzlePhreakPoPo 's answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Could this be:

> Down

I have to admit El-Guest gave me the biggest clue to my answer as I was looking at it the wrong way!

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that it's:

> Downloading

Comment: I like this answer a lot, especially because the word is going *down*, although (ROT13) gur uvqqra jbeq vf AJBQ juvpu vf QBJA onpxjneqf, fb gung zvtug freir na ryrzrag bs gur nafjre. To read that, simply head to [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/) and paste the illegible message into the upper box to convert it into a secret message. (I've written that in Rot13 coding in order to not spoil anything for other users attempting to solve this rebus puzzle.) Nonetheless, welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (PSE)**! Visit the [Help Center](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) for more info :D